# Always Getting Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, arrays

I have to find the maximum non-negative sub-array,i.e.the sum of elements of sub-array containing only non-negative terms should be maximum.If the sum of 2 sub-arrays is maximum then the one with the max length should be printed.If the length of the 2 sub-arrays is the same then the sub-array with lower starting index should be chosen.

I pass the input array to the function.Then run a loop.Inside that loop first I ensure that the negative terms that may appear at the start of the array are not considered.Then find the sum of the sub-array containing non-negative terms and find the max sum.

```
void largestsubarr(int* A,int n1,int* len1){
    int i=0,j,k=0,count;
    A=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n1);
    len1=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n1);
    int subarr[n1][n1];
    int largest=0,max_cnt=0;
    while(i<n1){
        int sum=0;
        count=0;
        while(A[i]<0)
            i++;
            //The first non negative term

        while(A[i]>=0)
        {
            count++;
            sum+=A[i];
            i++;
        }
        if(sum>largest)
        largest=sum;
    }

    printf("The largest subarray sum : %d",largest);
    free(len1);
}
int main()
{
  int n;
  printf("Enter the no. of elements : ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  int* a=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
  int* res=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
  printf("Enter the elements of the array :\n");
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
  printf("Address of a : %p",a);
  largestsubarr(a,n,res);
  free(a);
  free(res);
  return 0;
}

I am getting segmentation fault.Try to resolve it using gdb.Following is the output I get:

    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    0x0000555555554a54 in largestsubarr (A=0x555500000000, n1=0, 
    len1=0x0)
        at q2.c:24
    24        sum+=A[i];
```

Comment: Why do you pass an `int* A` parameter to your function and then immediately overwrite it with a `malloc`? Same with `len1`.

Comment: You are also failing to check the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: The inside while loops could be a problem, since the boundary check is based on `A[i]`, but you increment `i` in the loop. It could  easily be going over the `n1` of the outer loop.

Comment: Your problem is here `void largestsubarr(int* A,int n1,int* len1)` It should be `void largestsubarr(int** A,int n1,int** len1)`

Comment: Those inner while loops also need to test for the i<n1 condition, do favor for.  The VLA is quite risky, you'll easily invoke the bug this web site is named for.

Comment: Pretty sure this: `while(A[i]<0) i++;` is undefined behaviour. You've `malloc`'ed` `A` (haven't checked for NULL), and are just incrementing `i` without checking for out of bounds access. You might be reading memory you haven't allocated.

Comment: I removed the malloc statement and yet I am getting the same error.Moreover the idea was that in the first inner while loop if there are negative terms they would be skipped due to the loop and we can start focusing on the non-negative terms.Once that is done, the second loop will keep adding the non-negative terms till a negative term is encountered in which case the second inner loop stops and the outer while loop checks whether i<n1. If it is then the whole process is repeated.

Answer (score 0):

```
int subarr[n1][n1];
```

works on the stack and is probably limited. Depending on n1 you get a memory allocation error (if it works at all using a non-const value to locally declare an array).

Allocate subarr also in a dynamical 2D manner.

```
typedef int *PInt;
PInt* subarr=new PInt[n1];
for(int i=0;i<n1;i++) subarr[i]=new int[n1];
```